Most acidic hydrogen atom in an alphahydroxy ketone
My question is

Which Hydrogen atom is the most acidic in an alphahydroxy ketone?

I have learnt that acidic character arises from the formation of a stable conjugate base after deprotonation. A negative charge on a more electronegative atom is more stable than opposed to that on a less electronegative one.
In an alpha hydroxy ketone, will the hydrogen atom that is directly attached to the oxygen be more acidic than the alpha hydrogen located in between the ketonic and hydroxy group?

My reasoning behind this is that in the conjugate base, the negative charge is directly located on the oxygen atom whereas in the conjugate base obtained by the deprotonation of the alpha hydrogen, the negative charge undergoes resonance however, this occurs between carbon and oxygen which is less stable as opposed to the negative charge being located on only oxygen.
Am I correct?

Your reasoning is correct.
